# Application has "disconnected from its clients" while copying sheets

Tags: vba, excel

When trying to copy a sheet from another workbook, I'm getting an

> Automation error. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Here is the odd part, this only happens the second time I run the code, the first time I run it through, it works fine. The error is occurring in the following sub:

```
Sub importsettings(str1 As String)

'Import the relevant sheet information
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbksandpit.Activate


wbkInputs.Activate
On Error GoTo catch

**wbkInputs.Sheets(str1).Copy after:=wbksandpit.Sheets(wbksandpit.Sheets.Count - 1)**

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

catch:

    MsgBox str1 & " sheet does not exist!"
  Debug.Print Err.Description
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Menu").Activate
wbkInputs.Close (False)
Call unlock_all_cells
End
End Sub
```

The error is occurring on the copy line, the objects are defined in the following lines:

```
Set wbksandpit = ThisWorkbook
```

and

```
Set wbkInputs = Workbooks.Open(strfilepath, False, True)
```

I have tried stepping through the code the second time, and both objects are defined correctly in the immediate window. What's even more weird is that it will actually copy the first sheet (I call this four times with four different sheet names as `str1`), so the line is executing, but still throwing out the error message, I've tried ignoring that specific error, but the workbook then freezes, so it doesn't work with the other three sheets.

NB - I've tried resetting the worksheet variables, that doesn't work either and I've also tried to close that sheet on error and then re-open it. Again, it doesn't work.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Have you try with `.Move` rather than `Copy`? Are you variables still in scope (did you declare them as `Public`)?

Comment: Are there any hidden sheets in the workbook to which you're copying?

Comment: @R3UK, Yes, the variables are still in scope - I've done a full check and yes they are declared public.

Rory - There is one hidden sheet, but I'd be surprised if this is causing it to not work the second time? As I said, it works fine the first time.

NB - I've put in a workaround already where I just create a temporary copy of the import file and import from there, not elegant but effective for now, I'd still be interested to know why this happens though. The error seems to be caused by opening the *same* file twice (opening new timestamped copies, doesn't cause it).